# What does $∫ρ(x)dx=∫ρ(x)ϕ(x)dx$ imply about $ϕ(x)$?

Tags: integration, riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry

What does $$\intop_{D}\rho(x)dx=\intop_{D}\rho(x)\phi(x)dx$$
  imply about $\phi(x)$
  for some positive definite function $\rho(x)$
  which satisfies $$\intop_{D}\rho(x)dx=M$$

For some nonzero M. $\phi(x)$ and $\rho(x)$ 
  are both continuous, smooth, nontrivial (i.e. $\phi,\rho\neq1$
 ) I have an argument/proof I'll post later to the effect that:

$$\intop_{D}\rho(x)dx=\intop_{D}\rho(x)\phi(x)dx\quad\Longrightarrow\quad\intop_{D}\mid\phi(x)\mid^{2}dx=1$$
However; I'm not 100% sure about it, would appreciate any thoughts. thank you!

**EDIT**

As I've learned more about the math behind this problem, it has become evident to me that this problem is more deep than I had initially considered. I had tried to give a “watered down” version (ie the one above) but I think I need to get more into the mathematical detail behind this:

I was considering compact 4-dimensional (pseudo) Riemannian metric spaces without boundary such that the volume of the space is given by:

$$V=\intop_{M}\sqrt{|g|}d^{4}x$$

What I've come to realize is that I'm looking for the set of local conformal transformations $\tilde{g}=u(x)^{2}g$ such that the volume of the manifold is unchanged:

$$\intop_{M}\sqrt{|g|}d^{4}x=\intop_{M}\sqrt{|\tilde{g}|}d^{4}x=\intop_{M}u(x)^{4}\sqrt{|g|}d^{4}x$$

I had initially “posed this question for a 1-dimensional space” in my initial question. I've further come to realize that the ricci curvature of the space for $g$ needs to be constant whereas for $\tilde{g}$ it is not constant.

This then ties the problem immediately to the well-known Yamabe problem (though I have only just realized this). Essentially my question is are the above conditions sufficient to ensure there exists such a function $u$? What are the conditions placed upon $u$? (such as the attempted integration condition I originally tried to place) Note I study physics and have been a bit “out of my depth” on this problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your result is false. For example, $D=[0,1],\rho=1,\phi=\begin{cases} 3 & 0 \leq x < 1/2 \\ -1 & 1/2 \leq x \leq 1 \end{cases}$. It should be possible to mollify this to get the same thing.

Comment: Apologies, I should have noted that they were smooth continuous functions, Just edited the question

Comment: As I said, this doesn't really matter: define $f$ to be $6$ on $[0,1/4]$, $-2$ on $[3/4,1]$, and smoothly go between the two in such a way as to have integral zero on $[1/4,3/4]$.

Comment: honestly, I didn't have piece wise functions in mind when I was working on this, but rather explicit functions. However I see your point

Comment: Try to get the distinction between "piecewise" and "not piecewise" out of your head. Functions map things to things, it doesn't matter how we describe them.

Comment: @Ian I may have inadvertently assumed $\phi$ was also positive definite in my own answer.

Comment: Then you have actually written a hypothesis that does you some good, but maybe not very much. For instance what if $D=(0,1]$ and $\rho=x^{-2/3}$? In this case you can choose $\phi$ with $\| \phi \|_{L^2}=1$ such that $\int \rho \phi dx$ is arbitrarily large; correspondingly that means you can have the integral be equal to $M$ when $\| \phi \|_{L^2}$ is arbitrarily small.

Comment: @Ian I appreciate your thoughts, I probably should have stated the original problem more specifically.  For my specific problem, D is actually a compact manifold of dimension 3 and the integral is over the whole of it. I didn't want to get too specific for my question.

Comment: So are $\rho,\phi$ bounded, then (being continuous on a compact)? If they are bounded and positive and the space has finite measure then something like your result should indeed hold.

Comment: @Ian I don't think I actually did assume that; however to be continuous and have a finite integral, I would expect them to be bounded above (and they're already bounded below).  Honestly this is a physics problem, I find the math section infinitely more helpful generally.  Thanks again.  I'll post my own "proof" after work

Comment: That's just because I chose $\rho=1$. I could've done this over with some other $\rho$, though.

Comment: @Ian Yeah, that was dumb, I've just posted what I had gathered. Thanks again

Comment: @Ian that was a dumb mistake on my part, if you've any further interest, I've posted the main problem, including the differential equation here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1791183/normalization-condition-for-a-solution-to-a-differential-equation

Comment: @Ian    After a long time, I've come back to this problem knowing a bit more of the details surrounding it.

Answer (score 0):

If $\rho$ an arbitrary  continuous function in an open inverval, then: $$\int \rho(x)(1-\phi(x))dx = 0 \Rightarrow 1-\phi(x)=0 $$ 
Find out here (a general case):
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_lemma_of_calculus_of_variations

Comment: "for some positive definite function $\rho(x)$"

Comment: This should be a comment, I think. By OP's language, it seems as though $\rho$ is fixed.

Comment: Not necesary positive, but  $1-\phi(x)$, it should be an arbitrary continuous function.

Comment: This issue here is that $\phi$ doesn't equal 1

Comment: Read the lemma you link: "for **all** compactly supported smooth functions". If it it's true for all $\rho$ then $\phi = 1$, but that is not the question asked here.